# How can I build programme based on nfc technology?

Tags: nfc, android-beam

I'm trying to write a programme, that is going to use nfc technology to transfer data between phones. The problem is, that I don't really know how to start it, what language or libraries should I choose? Or maybe there are any other technologies, that will allow me to transfer data via touching phones?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your app following the [Android-Beam guide](https://developer.android.com/training/beam-files)
It can be written in Kotlin/Java Language.
Note that from Android 10, Beam feature is deprecated.
Instead you will have a new feature called Fast Share that uses Wifi Direct and other methods of pairing rather than touching.